# What does WHERE NOT EXISTS mean?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

```
INSERT INTO Track(title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count) 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM Track WHERE title = ?)
```

What is the meaning of `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in this query?

Or please can someone translate these sql to words?

Comment: `WHERE NOT EXISTS` means where it doesn't exists in the select query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the first part of the query

```
INSERT INTO Track(title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count) 
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
```

does not exist in the subquery that's being run

```
(SELECT * FROM Track WHERE title = ?)
```

I feel like this might be a case where might want to look into using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/

Answer (score 0):

Insert what i'm giving you as ? variables into the track table, but only if the title is not already in there.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, what it means in this case is that you are not inserting duplicate titles -- assuming that the `?` for the title being inserted is the same as the `?` for the title checked in the subquery.

You should actually *also* have a unique index/constraint on `title`, so the database enforces this at the database level.

In my opinion, a better approach is to use [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

```
alter table track add constraint unq_track_title unique (title);

INSERT INTO Track(title, album_id, genre_id, len, rating, count) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
    ON CONFLICT (title) IGNORE;
```

This is also thread-safe, so multiple inserts of the same row by different users is not allowed.

All that said, different tracks CAN have the same title.  You probably want the unique index on `album_id`/`title`.